# Bottoms of badges are cut off on mobile site

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web, android

This has been going on for a couple of days:

[image: badges are cut off]

The bottoms of the badges are cut off on the mobile site.

Android 5.1.1, on both the default browser and Chrome 46.

Comment: The badges for the iOS mobile site is whole, but tinier and lower. That would not be relevant to this question, of course.

Comment: Regarding your comment: the mobile sites are same for everything (unlike the apps)...

Comment: @nicael Really. I'm starting to think my phone is broken... I checked on an old phone running android 2.2.1 this morning and again it looked whole but tiny and misaligned.

Comment: It's not broken :) The reason is your android phone having lower screen PPI. On your iPhone, the badges look tinier, because having the same size, they are displayed on the higher-PPI screen. (PPI=pixels per inch) **Don't delete, that's a valid bug!!!**

Comment: @nicael I've undeleted it. I'm wondering if it is a problem with the android versions, because I think it's highly unlikely that a phone my mom bought over three years ago should have a higher PPI than a phone I bought a month ago. (P.S. I don't have an iPhone. I was looking on an iPad Mini, without that fancy retina stuff.)

Comment: New iPads Mini also have Retina display. And what's that thing about old and new phones. An older phone shows it correct?

Comment: Third comment from the top: it shows fine on android 2.2.1. And I have iPad Mini 1, which I'm fairly certain doesn't have retina.